# Abrir Facebook no navegador

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Criei um aplicativo para Facebook que, resumidamente, em determinado momento ele faz o upload de uma foto para o álbum do visitante, e depois uso o `var janela = window.open({urldafoto})` para abrir essa foto no album. Até aqui tudo bem.

Eu precisava saber quando essa janela seria fechada, e como o `onunload` não funciona para outros domínios, fiz um script que usa o `setTimeout` verificando a propriedade `janela.closed`.

No PC esse aplicativo está funcionando 100% como deveria.

O problema é quando abro ele pelo celular com Android, pois quando clico no botão para abrir a janela, o Android me pergunta se quero abrir usando o app do Facebook (instalado no celular), e isso atrapalha o `janela.closed`.

Existe alguma forma de forçar o Android abrir o link no próprio navegador em uso?

Se tiverem alguma outra ideia de como monitorar se a janela for fechada, também seria interessante saber.